# MongoDB find substructure

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongodb with a table named Patient. When I display the content with MongoVUE I see my Patients in this format:

```
/* 0 */
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("547c4aa9dbe9665042dddf76"),
  "Patient" : {
    "Maidenname" : { },
    "Phone" : {
      "Type" : { },
      "Number" : { }
    },
    "Citizenship" : { },
    "SSN" : 1234567,
    "Profession" : { },
    "systemUID" : { },
    "lid" : 111,
    "system" : "abc",
    "Address" : {
      "Street" : { },
      "State" : { },
      "Zip" : { },
      "Country" : { },
      "City" : { }
    },
    "Lastname" : "asdf",
    "Firstname" : "Test",
    "Birthdate" : 19000101,
    "Identifier" : {
      "id" : 123,
      "system" : "abc",
      "UID" : { }
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to make a find on the field Firstname with value Test, this is my query:

```
db.Patient.find({Firstname:"Test"})
```

But it returns 0 rows.
I also tried this one:

```
db.Patient.find({Patient : {Firstname:"Test"}})
```

Also 0 rows returned.

When I do a find like this:

```
db.Patient.find()
```

I get all data. (also the one with "Firstname" : "Test")

Can anyone help me with that find query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should try this it work well

```
db.patiens.find({"Patient.Firstname":"Test"})
```

Comment: Thank you it worked! will accept your answer as soon as i can.

Comment: Thank! I've learned the hard way that `find({"Data":{"UserId": user_id}})` will not yield the same result as `find({"Data.UserId": user_id})`.
It was all in documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents
"Note: When querying using dot notation, the field and nested field must be inside quotation marks."

Answer (score 2):

Since Firstname is in Patient object, it is its property you need to select is as

```
db.Patient.find({"Patient.Firstname":"Test"})
```